# How to seek Previous video when backing video in 0:0 Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I use  Videoview for Play video and I use seekto for seek in video.
And Now I want when use mediaControler and pree back key and Arrived 00:00
video is stoped and previous video Begging play video.
How find that video is 00:00 time ?

[image]